# Как в балун метки (Яндекс карты API) добавить php код

Tags: php, yandex-maps-api

Необходимо, чтобы в балуне выводился php код, а точнее результат его выполнения.
Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: нужные данные из php можно перенести на страницу в виде объекта js. И уже эти данные использовать в картах

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<style>
  body, #map {
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  let data = <?php
      $arr = array(
          'coords' => [60, 30.3], 
          'body' => 'this data', 
          'footer' => 'from php'
      ); 
      echo json_encode($arr);
  ?>;

  ymaps.ready(() => {
    let myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: data.coords,
        zoom: 15,
        controls: []
    });
    myMap.balloon.open(data.coords, {
        contentBody: data.body,
        contentFooter: data.footer
    });
  });
</script>
```